# How to add entries for reservation system in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello im trying to make a Restaurant-Website with a simple booking-system for tables with ruby on rails (V.: 3.2.13). I have 3 tables: Customers(name,Email), Reservations(table_id,customer_id), Tables(seats,area).

I have configured the models like the following:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :table
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :tables, :through => :reservations
end

class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :customers, :through => :reservations
end
```

I made a search with the form_tag for the choice of a table. If the customer found the right table he can click on the "book this table"-link and then he is directed to new_customer_path to apply his name and Email address. My problem is now the reservation. How can I dynamically/automatically add reservations with the chosen table and the new created customer?

I tried something like this in the CustomerController but it doesnt work:

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  table = Table.find(params[:table_id])
  @reservation = @customer.Reservation.build(:table => table)
  @reservation.save
end
```

Could you please tell me how to add reservations.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@reservation = @customer.reservations.build(table: table).save!`

Thanks

Comment: Well the problem is that an error occurs with`table = Table.find(params[:table_id])`:Couldn't find Table without an ID. I guess the param :table_id is not accessible. Do you have any idea how to fix that? Thanks

Comment: yes can you check the log whther your views send `table_id` as a parameter or not

Comment: like this way `:table_id => 2` in log in parameters

Comment: Just for curiosity may I know your name?

Comment: Well Im Mike. Well when i click on the "book this table"-button, I can display the Table_id in the customer_new-view and it is also shown in the address bar.

Comment: Mike, Please send the id while you calling the controller method as we did it for show method same just send the table_id so if you used form then you can do `<%=hidden_field_tag :table_id, any_id %>`

Comment: I added the `hidden_field_tag` in the form for a new customer. But I think this isnt correct jet. Now the error msg is `Couldn't find Table with id=`. Sorry for my sucky Railsskills...

Comment: can you show me your database is there any table already created?

Comment: create a Table `table = Table.create(...)` then `@reservation = @customer.reservations.build(table: table).save!`

Comment: In the customer controller? Well all tables already exist. I just want to add the reservation entries

Comment: Mike you did not get me I am telling check in your database tables in those tables there should be a table name as `Table` it should be populated by data

Comment: Sorry for my bad interpretation. Ok there is a table named "Table". It has some records. And now? Btw what does `(table: table)` in `@reservation = @customer.reservations.build(table: table).save!` mean?

Comment: can you please do this in your controller `table=Table.first` then `@reservation = @customer.reservations.build(table: table).save!`

Comment: Ok Ive done that. Now this is displayed `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: table`. Is ´(table: table)´ correct?

Comment: then add `attr_accessible :table` in reservation model and then restart and it will work like a charm....thanks

Comment: Ok I added it. This `Validation failed: Customer can't be blank´ means that i have to save the customer first right?

Comment: Well thank you very much so far. Now i just have to fix the correct table_id and then everything is fine :).

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
@reservation = @customer.reservations.build
# set table:
@reservation.table = table
# save record:
@reservation.save
```